# How do you check if something has declined by 10% without an if statement?

Tags: python, vectorization

I am given two numbers `x` and `y` in Python, and I'm asked if `y` represents a 10% decrease from `x`.

What is the best way of doing this without an `if-statement`? I am looking to vectorize this operation, so it'd be good to have a branchless form.

The verbose check would be:

```
def check(x,y):
    if x < 0:
        return y < x*1.1
    else:
        return y < x*0.9
```

I considered

```
def check(x,y):
    return y < x * (1.1 if x < 0 else 0.9)
```

but that's just an inline `if-statement`.

Comment: Plain Python doesn't support vector operations. Just use an `if` statement...

Comment: `return x*0.9 < y < x*1.1`

Comment: try `return (y - x) / x <= .10`

Comment: FWIW, simple branches like this *can* be vectorized.  But whether or not python (or numpy, etc) can use those instructions is another story.

Comment: @dawg If the goal is to avoid branching at the hardware level, then comparison operators are also not permissible.

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify *why* you don't want an if statement? Python integers *don't* vectorise but *do* use branching for their operations anyways, so the stated reason doesn't apply.

Comment: I'm working on many-ish, large-ish numpy arrays, so I want to implement this using array level operations. The answer by @Plonetheus is good - I can adapt that to the numpy operations. ie. `(x-y).div(x.abs()) > 0.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I think this should work:

```
def ten_percent_decrease(x: int, y: int):
    """
    check if y is 10% less than x
    """
    return (x - y) / abs(x) > 0.1
```

Note: the code breaks if you give 0 for x.  I'm not sure what you want the expected output to be in that case, but you can adjust it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my issue. As per my comment above, I extended it to numpy arrays.